# geometrically speaking, what does a rectangular matrix, reprsent?

Tags: linear-algebra

In general, a squre matrix or order n , represents a space ,$\mathbb{R}^{n}$,
for instance ,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
reprsents $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

but what does
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
represent geometrically? Is it just two vectors instead of a coordinate system, or is it something like
$\mathbb{R}^{2.5}$?

Comment: usually a matrix represent a linear function (between vector spaces)

Comment: A matrix $n\times m$ represents a linear transformation T between the vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. The set of solutions of $T\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: @Masacroso, yes, but as I'm not yet in college, I'm more interested in what it means geometrically

Comment: @Ixion, Isee. Thanks!

Comment: Your first assertion is not correct. An element of $\mathbb R^n$ is represented by a vector, not a square matrix.  The matrix you wrote is the identity matrix. It represents the identity map on $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: oh, OK. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Every matrix is a transformation. A square matrix takes input and outputs a thing of the same dimensions.

A rectangular matrix, say the one you gave, can be applied to a 3D vector. However, it outputs a 2D vector. The reason for it is that you have just reduced the dimension of your space. Take every transformed basis vector and you will see that it lies on a plane now. However, this plane is still in a 3D space, the same you started with.

Comment: oh,I see. Thanks !

Comment: You can also see from the transformation where the plane actually is in the 3D space. Go figure it out.

Comment: There is a natural way to do the embedding but I wouldn't say the embedding is automatic. And it certainly isn't automatic when you get into abstract spaces...

Comment: @ArturWiadrowski, I would think it's the lane spanned by i X k, is that right?